# Magento CE breaks with MariaDB 10.6.13 galera cluster

Tags: magento2, database, mariadb

I run a Magento CE store with 3 DB servers (galera cluster). When upgrading Magento from 2.3.4 to Magento 2.4.6, also upgraded MariaDB from 10.4 to 10.6, and PHP from 7.4 to 8.1, to match [Magento System Requirements](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/system-requirements.html).

Latest version in MariaDB repo was 10.6.13. Magento did not like the latest MariaDB and threw exception "This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'GET_LOCK in cluster (WSREP_ON=ON)'"

Whats going on? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Someone already found this issue and logged it here: [[bitnami/mariadb-galera] 10.6.13 - Lock Issue #16868](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/16868). On the same page, someone else had a workaround - downgrade to MariaDB 10.6.12 or upgrade to 10.6.14

The breaking change in MariaDB was made in 10.6.13 and reverted in 10.6.14 -
[MariaDB Changelog 10.6.14](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-10-6-14-release-notes/)